# Missing context menus in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide, editor, eclipse-indigo

I use Eclipse 3.7 to edit JSP files in the default Java EE and Debug perspectives.

I noticed that whenever I debug, the usual context menu items are missing (e.g., "Inspect", "Watch"). I'll show a screenshot below.

[image]

What makes it even weird is that these menu items appear when I'm debugging in the PHP perspective.

Comment: Not dependent on the JSP editor that shows the code, at least no difference between JBoss JSP editor and the (default) WTP JSP editor.